# PHPMailer: How to make reply to all CC automatic

Tags: phpmailer

I'm trying to make a sort of 'discussion' list using PHPMailer, so my concern is how can i make the reply to members in CC automatic, i mean that if one recipient answer a mail, all emails in CC receive the email with need to select reply to all.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. That's not what CC is for. What you can do is put multiple addresses in Reply-To. In PHPMailer you'd do that like this:

```
$mail->addReplyTo('address1@example.com', 'User One');
$mail->addReplyTo('address2@example.com', 'User Two');
```

When the user replies to that, the reply will be sent to both addresses.